# Facebook fresco library: ZoomableDraweeView check image is zoomed or in original state

Tags: android, fresco

I am using ZoomableDraweeView from [arlindiDev/FrescoDoubleTapZoom](https://github.com/arlindiDev/FrescoDoubleTapZoom)  in my app it is working perfectly for pinch and double tap zoom effect but problem is that I want a zoom checking listener in my Mainactivity.class that check whether image is zoom state or in original state.

```
ChechZoom.java 
interface public interface CheckZoom {

        void isZoomed(Boolean zoom);

    }
```

implemented in **mainactivity.java** to observe zoom state

and called in AnimatedZoomableController.java 's method

```
public void zoom(PointF viewPoint) {

      PointF imagePoint = mapViewToImage(viewPoint);

      if(getScaleFactor() < getMaxScaleFactor()) {
        **checkZoom.isZoomed(true);**
        zoomToPoint(getMaxScaleFactor(), imagePoint, viewPoint, LIMIT_ALL, 400, null);
      } else {
        **checkZoom.isZoomed(false);**
        zoomToPoint(getMinScaleFactor(), imagePoint, viewPoint, LIMIT_ALL, 400, null);
      }
  }
```

it work fine for double tap zoom effect notify image is zoomed or not in main activity.

but problem is where should i put this line of code **checkZoom.isZoomed(true or false);** to detect pinch zoom effect.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out to me, try using the the observer pattern. Can you also add your code from your project.

Comment: check again  question